# How to Rewrite IIS Domain To subDomain?

Tags: iis

I need when user type in browser:

> mydomain.com/test

I show him data from:

> test.mydomain.com

and don't change domain.
How to show data for members and not change domain with ReWrite IIS?
Or help me another option for work it.

Comment: If you use rewrite as action (instead of redirect) the URL in browser address bar won't change.

Comment: please give me a sample to change domain.
I tried it but not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, I suggest you could try to use below url rewrite rule.
It will rewrite the url from mydomain.com/test to test.mydomain.com.

Notice:This rule will only mathch the test in your url, if you want to match all words behind the slash, you should use `.*`.

Rewrite rule:

```
   <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Test" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="test" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://{R:0}.mydomain.com" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
  </rewrite>
```

Comment: Could you please tell me how it doesn't work? Does this show any error message?Do you install the ARR feaure in your IIS? Besides,If your application is asp.net MVC or application which contains its speical route, it may feel your setting is useless.

Comment: subdomain project MVC and Domain Project in Angular and I need see My SubdomainsData in Main Domain